# Access to Azure KeyVault with Azure.Identity in Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-keyvault

I have a Xamarin.Forms application. I need an Azure Storage to store some data. I don't want to store the Shared Access Signature (SAS) in my application, obviously.

In my application, I've develop a `KeyVaultService`:

```
private readonly Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.SecretClient _keyVaultSecretClient;

public KeyVaultService() 
    => _keyVaultSecretClient = new(
        new Uri("https://foo.vault.azure.net/"), 
        new DefaultCredential());

// ...

public async Task<string> GetSecretAsync(string secretName)
{
    // ...
    var response = await _keyVaultSecretClient.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
    // ...
    return response.Value.Value;
}
```

A `AzureStorageService`:

```
private readonly IKeyVaultService _keyVaultService;
public AzureStorageService() => _keyVaultService = DependencyService.Get<IKeyVaultService>();

public async Task<byte[]> GetFooAsync()
{
    var connectionString = await _keyVaultService.GetSecretAsync(STORAGE_CONNECTIONSTRING);
    _blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, CONTAINER_NAME);
}
```

And it's called like that:

```
byte[]? fooBytes = await _azureStorageService.GetFooAsync();
await DoSomething(fooBytes);
```

## Tests

The second parameter of `SecretClient` is a `Azure.Identity.TokenCredential` derived class. With my `_keyVaultSecretClient` instance, in my `KeyVaultService`, I have tried to use some classes (`DefaultAzureCredential`, `ClientSecretCredential`, ...):

### `DefaultAzureCredential` and `ClientSecretCredential`

```
public KeyVaultService() => new(new Uri("foo...."), new DefaultAzureCredential())
```

and

```
public KeyVaultService() => new(new Uri("foo...."), new ClientSecretCredential(TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
```

An exception throws:

```
Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: 

'ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: Confidential Client flows are not available on mobile platforms or on Mac.See https://aka.ms/msal-net-confidential-availability for details.'

Inner Exception:

PlatformNotSupportedException: Confidential Client flows are not available on mobile platforms or on Mac.See https://aka.ms/msal-net-confidential-availability for details.
```

> And I don't want to keep Tenant ID, Client ID or Secret ID in my code

### `EnvironmentCredential`

```
public KeyVaultService() => new(new Uri("foo...."), new EnvironmentCredential())
```

I have add 3 environment variables on my Windows: `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` and `AZURE_TENANT_ID`.

[image]

`AuthenticationFailedException` is thrown, again.

### ManagedIdentityCredentials

```
public KeyVaultService() => new(new Uri("foo...."), new ManagedIdentityCredential(CLIENT_ID))
```

Another exception throws:

```
Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: 

'ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No Managed Identity endpoint found.'
```

Where and how can I add an `Identity endpoint`?

> The client ID is in the code!! Nooo :(

---

### Information

**Mobile Apps + Key Vault Don't do it**

I have read this blog post: https://codemilltech.com/mobile-apps-azure-keyvault-dont-do-it/, But... If an anonymous user found the url of my Azure Function... He can read my Key Vault address... And my application throws the same exceptions... I think is my approach.

Develop an Azure Function which access to Key Vault and his secrets, then sends them back to me through an API? Ooh: All of my secrets can be leaked. No thanks.

---

I have read the link provided by the exception (https://aka.ms/msal-net-confidential-availability). MSAL? Why for Azure? From what I understood, MSAL allows to connect to Microsoft Graph and Office 365 APIs...

---

### In resume

I understand that my approach is not available on mobile platforms (The exception is self-explanatory enough to guess, I promise) - because a phone is not entirely secure device?

So,
**what is the implementation to use an Azure Key Vault or another solution to securely access to my Azure Storage?**

In fact,

- I want to have not the secrets in my code;
- I want access to an Azure Storage with a SAS, to a SAP server with username/password and another external services (stored in the Key Vault - or another securely way).

Someone has an idea?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Ideally you should have an API endpoint from where you should request SAS token and use that token in your mobile application to interact with Azure Storage.

Comment: OK, if this is a mobile app, rather than reading Azure Storage directly, perhaps construct a REST endpoint in an App Service that uses Managed Identity (DefaultCredential) to access it for you?

Comment: @Andres - Any update how did you resolve this - I am stuck in exactly same situation